# Can't Delete a row from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm simply trying to delete a row from a DataGridView. Basically, the first column is a combo box, and when the user selects "[Remove]" from the combo box, the entire row should be removed. So I have this OnCellEndEdit event code:

```
if (grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && grid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()=="[Remove]") {
  grid.EndEdit();
  grid.Rows.RemoveAt(grid.CurrentRow.Index);
}
```

Rather than delete the row, this throws an exception:

**Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.**

I've tried moving the CurrentRow to a different column before I delete, like this:

```
DataGridViewRow deleteRow = grid.CurrentRow;
grid.CurrentRow.Selected = false;
grid.Rows[deleteRow+1].Selected = true;
grid.Rows.RemoveAt(deleteRow);
```

Same problem. The grid's AllowUserToDeleteRows attribute is true. I'm not binding data to this control.

I believe the problem lies in my tying to the CellEndEdit event, as if I delete the row from a button control's OnClick event, I'm okay.

Could I programatically trigger the button's OnClick event? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are already in the `OnCellEndEdit` call, so I dont think you need to call `grid.EndEdit()` again.  Try removing that call and see if the row gets removed.  I believe that error is caused because you could end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: It still happens, I added the EndEdit() in a futile attempt to avoid the error.

Comment: You might try removing the row in the CellValueChanged event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx  I'm not sure editing the grid in the editing events is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

use the following check before applying your edit:

```
public void myGrid_EndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
  if (!myGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected)
                return;
  //...rest of your code to apply edit below...
}
```

This should work with any cell being edited.(the edit-code is not applied when losing focus; Typing Enter would suffice to apply the edit)